# How to replace variables in statements for explain?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have the query:

```
SELECT
    <fieldname1>
FROM <tablename>
WHERE <fieldname2> = ANY(@variablename)
;
```

If I prefix it with `EXPLAIN` it errors with:

> [42703] ERROR: column "variablename" does not exist Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "<tablename>.<fieldnamex>".

How should I be replacing the `@variablename`? I know I can replace it with an:

```
array [1, 2, 3]
```

But that would affect explain I'd assume? For the most consistent explain result, should I try to be as close as possible to the regular average number of array items? Or what's a better way to explain such queries with a variable?

---

I need a reference or something to understand how to decide on what value to replace the variables with before an explain statement for the best estimate.

Comment: I don't understand what you want: `@variablename` clearly is client code, so of course you have to replace that with the real value to run the SQL statement `EXPLAIN`. Perhaps you can clarify your need.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for your attention, I've added another statement to better clarify my need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a prepared statement and a generic plan:

```
/* create a prepared statement with a parameter of the appropriate type */
/* $1 is a placeholder for the first parameter */
PREPARE stmt(integer[]) AS
SELECT fieldname1 FROM tablename WHERE fieldname2 = ANY($1);

/* force a generic plan */
SET plan_cache_mode = force_generic_plan;

/* show the generic plan */
EXPLAIN stmt(NULL);
```